# Java syntax: When declaring a string, why put "new" in front of the string instead of just simply assigning it

Tags: java, string, variables

Java syntax: When declaring a string, what is the purpose of the `new` keyword in front of the string instead of just simply assigning it.

Example:

```
String str = new String ("Welcome!");

String strTwo = "Welcome!";
```

What is the difference?

Comment: The first example creates a new string. The second uses the string literal pool. You should almost always opt for the second way.

Comment: also, by using new, you've actually done both, declared a literal and used new String() to make a new string based on that literal.

Comment: Please delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

`new String ("Welcome!")` allocates a new string that's a copy of the given string.

This is almost never useful since Java strings are immutable.

The one case where it makes a difference is the new string will not be `==` to the given string. You should compare strings with `.equals()` in the first place.

Note that Java string literals are interned into a table of all the string literals. That way they share storage. It also makes `==` work for two string literals, but again you should only do that in very special cases.

Mostly, I think programmers coming from C++ use `new` because there it's needed to convert a C string literal into a `std::string` object.

Comment: as a side note, a String actually consists of a String container object and a private char[] which contains the characters. When you use the copy constructor, it will create a new String object but internally reference the same char array. this can be done safely as String are immutable.